# How to setup a RoR application with SSO on Azure AD

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, single-sign-on, azure-active-directory, adal

I am struggling to setup a Ruby on Rails, [ActiveAdmin](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin) application which uses [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for authentication. I am using the [Azure AD strategy](https://github.com/AzureAD/omniauth-azure-activedirectory) for the omniauth strategy.

I have added omniauth strategy in `config/initializers/devise.rb`:

```
config.omniauth :azure_activedirectory, 'app id', 'azure tenant id'
```

Added the `Users::OmniauthCallbacksContoller`:

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def azure_activedirectory
    @user = AdminUser.from_omniauth(request.env['omniauth.auth'])

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => 'azure_activedirectory') if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session['devise.azure_activedirectory_data'] = request.env['omniauth.auth']
      redirect_to new_admin_user_registration_url
    end
  end

  def failure
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

And added the callback routes to `routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_config = ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  devise_config[:controllers][:omniauth_callbacks] = 'users/omniauth_callbacks'
  devise_for :admin_users, devise_config

  devise_scope :admin_user do
    get 'sign_in', :to => 'devise/sign_in', as: :new_admin_user_session
    get 'sign_out', :to => 'devise/sign_out', :as => :destroy_admin_user_session
  end

  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

  root to: redirect('/admin')
end
```

Added the `from_omniauth` method to `models/admin_user`:

```
class AdminUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :trackable, :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: [:azure_activedirectory]

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
    end
  end
end
```

But all I get when I run the application is the error: `The action 'sign_in' could not be found for Users::OmniauthCallbacksController`

I am at an end now, I do not know what else I have to do to get it working. https://github.com/AzureAD/omniauth-azure-activedirectory and https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview do not show any leads for me anymore on how to fix it.

Can anybody help me on what I do wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have been working on the project a bit more and been able to solve the Azure AD authentication. There are however a few things that we run into.

By default the azure active directory strategy generates routes without underscore. Thus make sure the model used for authentication uses:

> omniauth_providers: [:azureactivedirectory]

The model was also extended with the fields "provider" and "uid".

Devise will add a link (c.q. button) on the page to login. But our goal is to only support omniauth authentication, thus not having an additional login page. To achieve this, we added a redirect to get devise to forward authentication straight to the azure provider.

Also be cautious when changing the mapping (in the config/initializers/device.rb). We added a workaround in case Devise could not find the authentication failure handler for the :api scope. In our case we ended up in a loop, as due to the mapping, the authentication was not set correctly in our application. Our application directed us to Azure for authentication, while Azure redirected us back because we were authenticated already, followed by the application directing us... etc.

Below are a couple of code snippets that might be useful:

**config/routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_config = ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  # see https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/wiki/Log-in-through-OAuth-providers  
  # for how to combine settings in devise config from ActiveAdmin and SamlSessions
  devise_config[:controllers][:omniauth_callbacks] = 'omniauth_callbacks'
  devise_config[:skip] = [:sessions]
  devise_for :admin_users, devise_config

  devise_scope :admin_user do
    get 'sign_in', :to => redirect('/admin/auth/azureactivedirectory'), :as => :new_admin_user_session
    get 'sign_out', :to => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_admin_user_session
end

ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
...
...
```

**app/models/admin_user.rb**

```
class AdminUser < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :trackable, :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: [:azureactivedirectory]

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth['provider'], uid: auth['uid']).first_or_create do |user|
      user.email = auth['info']['email']
    end
  end
end
```

**app/controllers/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb**

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token

  def azureactivedirectory
    @user = AdminUser.from_omniauth(request.env['omniauth.auth'])

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => 'azure_activedirectory') if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session['devise.azure_activedirectory_data'] = request.env['omniauth.auth']
      redirect_to new_admin_user_registration_url
    end
  end

  def failure
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need this line:

```
get 'sign_in', :to => 'devise/sign_in', as: :new_admin_user_session
```

On the [Devise Docs](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview) it's saying that if you use:

```
devise_for :admin_users
```

The Devise will automatically create the routes for login, so you just have to use:

```
<%= link_to "Sign in with AzureAD", admin_user_omniauth_authorize_path(:azure_activedirectory) %>
```

I hope it helps you :)

**UPDATE**

When you sign in, you can specify the path you want the user to be redirected to, as you can see [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3A-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in-and-sign-out) and [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in), to do that you can specify methods like these on your application controller:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  current_user_path
end
```

and

```
def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  request.referrer
end
```

**UPDATE 2**

You're getting redirected from '/' to '/admin' because this line on your config/routes.rb

```
root to: redirect('/admin')
```

This is setting the root of your application, which the default it '/' to '/admin'. If you remove this line, rails will recognize the root of your application as '/'.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. Too bad though this solves the error, but introduces a new problem: I get redirected from `/` to `/admin` and vice versa.

Comment: @MichaelSommer i edited my answer to try to solve your problem, hope it works for you now.

Comment: When I remove the `root to:` people will not be redirected to `/admin` anymore and I do not expect my users to know that by themselves. My root has the entry for an api which does use Warden instead of devise.

Comment: The user is still not directed to the AzureAD login page with the suggested solution. They will stay unauthorized. And I want to use SSO without the use of a landing page where the user again has to click on any link before they get authorized.